# gcloud cloud functions deployment failure code 13 message=Failure in the execution environment"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Deploying cloud function with `gcloud` failed with below message,

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=13,
>   message=Failure in the execution environment

Couldn`t find much information about the error in the cloud function logs.

Running deploy with `--verbose debug` traces the functions called in the Cloud SDK directory and ends with displaying the below error,

> FunctionsError: OperationError: code=13, message=Failure in the
>   execution environment ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy)
>   OperationError: code=13, message=Failure in the execution environment

Answer (score 5):

Per this [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/64771090), the error is due to a very large package.json file hitting an internal restriction. Possible workarounds:

1- Installing your dependencies locally (through 'npm install') and deploying with `--include-ignored-files` flag.

2- Reduce your package.json to less than 4000 characters

This is an ongoing issue and you can follow the discussion on this [thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/64771090) for related updates.

Comment: Do you know if this will preclude the Cloud Function build process from installing _anything_ using package.json/NPM?

Answer (score 1):

For my case, it was a python environment, and the culprit was a dependency `yarl==1.5.1`.

As there are no logs, I couldn't tell exactly why `yarl` was causing the breakage, but downgrading to `yarl==1.3.0` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: How were you able to spot that the culprit was that one?

Comment: @TommasoGuerrini at the time, I spotted the issue by cherry-picking the dependencies until I found the one responsible for the build breakage. However, I have later found this page that outlines Google cloud function's dependency issues https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python

Comment: Thanks, I did the same!

Answer (score 0):

The status of firebase can be found under:
https://status.firebase.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing our experience here, with the hope it helps someone in the future.

In our case we got a similar error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=13, message=Error setting up the execution environment for your function. Please try deploying again after a few minutes.
```

This was caused by an import of `package.json` in the code to read out the version. I.e.:

```js
import { version } from '../package.json';
```

Transpilation and local invocation of the generated JS code worked as expected with the above line in our code base. After we removed the import, we were able to deploy the function agian.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the GCP errors are broad.

The solution to this for me was my `go.mod` file had `go 1.14` while the GCP only supports `go 1.11` or `go 1.13`